# Package name matches an existing developer's application (but it doesn't)

Tags: android, google-play, conflict, submission

I am trying to submit an application to the marketplace but when I try to upload I get a message:

> The package name of your apk (xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx) is the same as
>   the package name of another developer's application. Choose a new
>   package name.

My company has two apps in market already but the package names are distinct. I have queried the address https://market.android.com/details?id=xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx to check to make sure that it's not mistakenly identifying one of our other apps but it comes up as "Not Found" which should mean that this package name doesn't conflict.

Is there something else I should try to get this to work? I am going to try a small change to the package name and see if it will pass but this error shouldn't have occurred in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is better to rename the package in this way you avoid having problems.

Comment: Ultimately, I was forced to rename the package. At the end of the day I just needed the submission to pass. I don't understand why it would fail but at this point I've moved on.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the package id does exist, but the application is in an unpublished status at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name or contact google support